# I see absolutely nothing under Size Inspector in Interface Builder. I want to be able to set the Auto

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I see no settings at all under Size Inspector in Interface Builder, it is completely blank for my View, all labels and all buttons.  I am using xcode 4.6 and have 'Use Autolayout' unchecked and the metrics (Size, Status Bar, Top Bar, Bottom Bar) are all 'None'.  I need to be able to control the autoresizingmask, but why can't I see any size properties?

Comment: If you click on an element, then click the inspector, it should show up.  But your element needs to be selected.

Comment: Thanks Douglas, but it was even more lame than that....I just couldn't tell the group was collapsed.

Comment: Too funny, glad it worked out for you.  Welcome to SO.

Comment: Thank you, you should submit this answer and accept it. This has been driving me nuts all week, I did not notice it was collapsible and sometimes XCode automatically collapsed it I was quitting and restarting XCode to get it visible again.

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, I had the exact same problem. The group was collapsed...

Answer (score 47):

Once you switch to Size Inspector tab, directly under the icon there is a little header that says "View." If you hover over that some text appears that says "Show," because apparently that section can collapse down. Clicking the header should cause the options you expect to appear.

I wish they would make this more clear, because I completely missed it as well, and restarted Xcode several times.

Comment: You saved my day, this UI choice is a shame!

Comment: Wow.  What an amazingly unintuitive UI!  Thanks for letting us know.

Comment: I managed to fix this by selecting a non Interface Builder file such as a file.h, file.m, or file.swift and then switching back to the .xib or storyboard file I was having problems with and then it worked.

Comment: Couldn't find that button, maybe they eliminated it in version 7? Tried closing and reopening Xcode. Didn't work. Close just the storyboard tab and reopened it, that worked.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem using Xcode 5.0 but upon further investigation, discovered the dysfunction ran to a higher degree - all Inspector views in Xcode were blank for every control, and the Navigator buttons didn't work either.

The culprit seems to have been a conflict in versioning.  When I re-checked out trunk, Xcode returned to expected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Resizing the Xcode window made things right again for me - go figure.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me......

1. Clear Menu -> Recent Files
   i cleared last open storyboard from Recent files
2. Restart Xcode