# Inspector size on xcode 5 is showing nothing

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, xcode5, xcode-storyboard

In xcode 5 with iOS7 target project the size inspector in storyboard is not work. When I have one element selected like a button, view or anything else and I go to size inspector of storyboard all is empty showing nothing.

I tried restarting Xcode, unchecking Autolayout, uninstalling an reinstall Xcode and nothing. This problem persists.

Is very strange that on other Macs I open the project and size inspector works correctly then not is a project issue.

If someone have the same problem and solve it. Please tell me how can I fix.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I see absolutely nothing under Size Inspector in Interface Builder. I want to be able to set the Auto](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14610929/i-see-absolutely-nothing-under-size-inspector-in-interface-builder-i-want-to-be)

Answer (score 8):

The answer that helped me is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14610929/i-see-absolutely-nothing-under-size-inspector-in-interface-builder-i-want-to-be/19470105#19470105). MouseOver "View" shows Button "Show".

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall of MAC OS X solves this issue 100%. In inspector size. But in size inspector you've probably noticed the "Show"|"Hide" watermark an the right top corner of panel. I agree that these hidden invisible buttons in IB is not the best solution in terms of UX. But Apple knows better :)

Comment: OMG WTF? What is the possible reason behind that hidden button? Apple is probably the most arrogant company in terms of UX and whole IB is simply incredibly bad.